# Close Vote review thresholds

Tags: discussion, support, review, vote-to-close, rate-limiting

Recently on Ask Ubuntu Meta I asked this question

[Should we be able to review 40 close votes when the queue length is less than 1000?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11510/107450)

Because the review queue is, in my opinion, too long and bad questions and answers are taking too long to be closed.

The question has received a number of up votes and a few comments but no answer.

My understanding is that for close vote reviews each reviewer can review 20 votes if the length of the review queue is less than 1000 and 40 if the review queue length is longer.

Is this 1000 threshold changeable on a site by site basis and if it is: Are the thresholds for each review queue separate?

Note: I'm not requesting that this threshold be changed, at least not yet, I'm trying to establish what's possible.  We may decide we want to reduce it but not until there has been further discussion and we have reached a consensus as a community.

Comment: Not just close votes review but every review queue has [rate limiting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/187824).

Comment: @hims056 are these rate limits hard coded or configurable on a site by site basis?

Comment: I don't know. Hope for a positive responce from devs.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this 1000 threshold changeable on a site by site basis and if it
>   is: Are the thresholds for each review queue separate?

Technically, yes it is changeable. Reality, no they likely won't change it for Ask Unbuntu.

I don't think they would change it for Ask Ubuntu because they still haven't changed it for Stack Overflow, even when there was over ***80,000*** reviews in the Close Vote queue.

The 1 close vote DUP HAMMER for people with gold tag badges is network wide. The limits of 20 close votes for under 1000 review items is network wide.

So it looks like they don't have any plans to make this stuff changeable on a site per site basis.

Comment: This is the saddest thing I've heard all day. The math indicates that at the current settings (40@1000, 20<1000) that it would take 25 users to clear the queue if the 40 close reviews stayed static at that level when there were 1000 awaiting review, but when it drops to <1000 (999?) it would take 50 users doing their fair share to get the job done. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the logic used (if any) to reach these parameters. Perhaps the numbers were picked out of a hat or the idea was to **always** have a lot of questions in the close queue for some unfathomable reason.

Comment: @ElderGeek I'm not on AskUbuntu, but if it's anything like SO, it's just that people are not *fully* using their close vote privileges as they should. [read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285486/3041194). Basically, more people need to get involved in closing that have close privs. I see there are 10 mods on AU. If each of them did just like 50 reviews today *(mods can review unlimited amount)* the queue would likely be gone by the end of the day.

Comment: That explains a great deal. Thanks.